# Executar comandos do cmd pelo Java

Tags: java, string, cmd

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para executar comandos do cmd em java.
Pois bem, eu fiz isso:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Commands {

static final Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
static Process pro;
static BufferedReader read;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Start = "cmd /c start cmd.exe";

    try {
        pro = run.exec(Start);
        read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
        read.readLine();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

E da certo!
Mais como eu faço para executar mais comandos no cmd e mostrá-los ao usuário?

Comment: Você quer executar um comando de cada vez ou você quer executar todos ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conforme a está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157429/1518921) você pode pegar o output do `Process` usando `.getOutputStream()` e nele você irá adicionar os demais comandos, o código deve ficar assim:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Commands
{
    static final Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    static Process pro;
    static BufferedReader read;

    private static void showFB()
    {
        read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(read.readLine());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String Start = "cmd /c start cmd.exe";

        try {
            pro = run.exec(Start);
            showFB();//Mostra as resposta

            OutputStream out = pro.getOutputStream();

            out.write("cd C:/ /r/n".getBytes());
            out.flush();
            showFB();//Mostra as resposta

            out.write("dir /r/n".getBytes());
            showFB();//Mostra as resposta

            out.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Se você quiser executar vários comando ao mesmo tempo em `CMD` você pode usar o `&` (que também é compatível com outros sistemas operacionais), por exemplo:

```
set A=1& set B=2& set C=3& echo A& echo B& echo C& DIR
```

Use no seu código assim:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class Commands
{
    static final Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    static Process pro;
    static BufferedReader read;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] cmds = {
            "cmd /c start cmd.exe",
            "comando 2",
            "comando 3",
            "comando 4"
        };

        try {
            pro = run.exec(String.join("& ", cmds));

            read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
            read.readLine();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Notei que ao execultar `start` na verdade o cmd fica travado e por isto você não recebe as resposta, uma maneira que você pode testar é usar o `cmd /c` apenas, fiz um exemplo:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class Commands
{
    static final Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    static Process pro;
    static BufferedReader read;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] cmds = {
            "echo 2",
            "echo 3",
            "echo 4"
        };

        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                String.join("& ", cmds));

            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process p = builder.start();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while (true) {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Não sei se você está usando algum IDE para faciliar, mas se for compilar manualmente, faça isto:

```
javac Commands.java
java Commands ConsoleTest
```

O parametro `ConsoleTest` é para pegar as saidas do `System.out.println`