# Script para Telnet

Tags: java

Como criar um script com comandos previamente estabelecidos para o Telnet?
Na empresa onde trabalho, utilizamos o Telnet diariamente para configuramos ONUs, no entanto, por não termos uma equipe de programação, é uma tarefa bem manual e repetitiva, pois sempre damos os mesmos comandos.

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um script, preferencialmente em Java, para o Telnet ou se tem como criar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendo java não existe nada pronto que fará exatamente isto, você mesmo quem tem que criar, todavia **se já tem experiencia com Java**, então o caminho é usar isto:

- [**Executar comandos do cmd pelo Java**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57076/3635)

Deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class Commands
{
    static final Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    static Process pro;
    static BufferedReader read;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] cmds = {
            "telnet ...", //primeiro telnet
            "comando após o telnet",
            "telnet ...", //segundo telnet
            "comando após o telnet",
        };

        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                String.join("& ", cmds));

            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process p = builder.start();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while (true) {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println(line); //Exibe a resposta
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

você disse *preferencialmente java*, isso quer dizer que não exclui outras maneiras, você pode usar .bat do windows, ou .sh em sistemas linux ou unix (depende do seu caso), veja abaixo:

### Windows

Se for Windows pode colocar todos os comandos em um arquivo com a extensão `.bat`, algo como criar um arquivo, `comandos.bat` e adicionar um conteudo assim:

```
@echo off

telnet etc etc etc

pause
```

### Unix/Linux

Se for um sistema com nucleo Unix ou Linux, pode criar um arquivo com a extensão `.sh` (é opcional), pode chama-lo de `comando.sh` e adicionar os comandos assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

telnet etc etc etc
```

Depois de criar o arquivo .sh deve setar a permissão executável:

```
cd pasta/aonde/esta/o/seu/script
chmod +x comando.sh
```

O comando anterior define permissão para qualquer um poder executar o seu script, mas acaso só o seu usuário (dono do script) possa ser o unico a usá-lo, então execute o `chmod` assim:

```
chmod u+x comando.sh
```

### Nota importante

O `/bin/bash` é o caminho do bash, mas ele pode mudar de sistema operacional, para sistema operacional, não existe um caminho padrão entre os diversos sistemas com núcleos baseados em Linux e Unix, leia isto para mais detalhes:

- [Qual a diferença de /bin/bash e /usr/bin/env bash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143822/3635)

Comment: O único problema deste comando do Telnet que você mencionou, é que para acessar a ONU, eu preciso inserir Login e Senha, mas desconheço algum comando que faça isso, saberia me dizer algum?

Comment: @FernandoCampanate esse ONU seria uma página web?

Comment: ONU é um equipamento de Fibra Óptica. Ele converte o sinal da Fibra Óptica, em sinal que nosso Roteador possa interpretar. Dá pra se dizer que é o mesmo acesso de um Roteador.

Comment: @FernandoCampanate vc acessa ele via CMD ou terminal também? Se for isto, poderia dar um exemplo com dados ficticios para eu criar algo que funcione aproximadamente para ti?

Comment: Eu acesso pelo terminal do Linux. 
telnet <ip>
   login
   senha