# Como executar e exibir log do CMD?

Tags: java, cmd

Eu vi alguns exemplos de como "executar" comandos do CMD, pela aplicação, porém, estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades. O que estou tentando fazer, é dar um `cd` na pasta do oracle, e depois, executar o `Backup.exe`, e "setar" no `JTextArea` o log do cmd. Porém, não estou tendo retorno de nada.

Alguém pode me dar um direcionamento?

Obs: eu não coloquei no caminho a parte de executar o bat do `Backup.exe`, pois ainda não consegui acessar o diretório.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CmdTest extends JFrame {
    private JTextField diretorio = new JTextField();
    private JTextArea log = new JTextArea();
    private JButton jButton = new JButton("Executar");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new CmdTest();
        });
    }

    public CmdTest() {
        setTitle("Teste CMD");
        add(painel());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        diretorio.setText("C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/bin");
    }

    private JPanel painel() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        painel.add(diretorio, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        painel.add(log, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        painel.add(jButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        diretorio.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 20));
        log.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 90));
        action();
        return painel;
    }

    private void action() {
        jButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            performBackup();
        });
    }

    private void performBackup() {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + diretorio.getText());
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = builder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while (true) {
            try {
                line = r.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Executar comandos do cmd pelo Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57073/executar-comandos-do-cmd-pelo-java)

Comment: @Articuno eu tentei seguir, mais não consegui

Comment: Do jeito que ta la, eu consegui copiar o log para a textarea sem problemas. Acho q voce nao pode dar cd, passa o caminho do arquivo direto, cd nao irá funcionar, ao menos nos testes que fiz ele foi inutil para listar o diretorio.

Comment: Se o objetivo é somente executar o .exe, não é necessário entrar no diretório, basta chamar o exe com o caminho completo, por exemplo: C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/bin/Backup.exe

Comment: @Articuno mesmo tirando CD, ele ainda não funciona. Consegue me mostrar como fez ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos ja testou a solucao do pedro?

Comment: @Articuno sim, ele me retorna → java.lang.Exception: 
'C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/bin' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: @GustavoSantos Testei a solução do Pedro e ela é funcional. Basta passar o caminho completo do arquivo para o método dele. Se está dando erro, o problema  é em outra coisa não mencionada nem no codigo e nem na pergunta,

Answer (score 0):

Segue um método genérico, onde você passa o comando, no seu caso, o caminho completo + o nome do executável, e ele retorna uma string com o resultado do processo.

```
/**
 * Executa um comando no CMD.
 * @param comando
 * @return a string de retorno do comando passado por paramêtro
 * @throws Exception caso o comando retore um código de erro
 */
public String executa(String comando) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder standartOutput = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder errorOutput = new StringBuilder();
    int exitStatus;

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc;

    proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /C SET \"NOPAUSE=true\" && " + comando);

    exitStatus = proc.waitFor();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    String s;

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        standartOutput.append(s);
        standartOutput.append("\n");
    }

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        errorOutput.append(s);
        errorOutput.append("\n");
    }

    if (exitStatus != 0 || !errorOutput.toString().isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception(standartOutput + "\n" + errorOutput);
    }

    return standartOutput.toString();
}
```